# how to get all methods of groups in ansible?

Tags: ansible

i'm learning ansible's playbook, but i come across a question. What does following sentence mean?

```
groups.get(mon_group_name, [])
```

and how to get all method of groups and it's meaning? such as `groups.keys` and `groups.get`

Answer (score 3):

Ansible is written in Python, so there are a lot of Python goodies inside.

`groups` is a [Magic Variable](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_variables.html#magic-variables-and-how-to-access-information-about-other-hosts) which stores information about groups and hosts in that groups.
It is of type [dict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict) – keys are group names and values are lists of hosts in that groups.

`groups.get(mon_group_name, [])` – this means: try to get a list of hosts from group with name stored in variable `mon_group_name`, if no such group return empty list `[]`.

All available methods of dict type you can see in the Python docs I linked above.